# Switching from intel to amd without reinstalling software, is it possible?

Tags: cpu

I'm soon going to be upgrading my hardware and I'm planning on switching to an AMD processor.

As I have plenty of stuff I'd really like to avoid having to reinstall my software, so I'm planning to change the CPU, MB and RAM.

My question is, is this going to work? Will any of my software need to be compiled specifically for the new CPU if both are x64?

Additionally there's a bunch of firmware installed for intel as I can see with:

```
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/ -type f -name '*.ko' | grep intel | wc -l
115
```

Will I need to install similar for amd, thus will require a live image as well?

I'm using debian 11 if it matters.

Comment: *I'm planning to change only the CPU, MB and RAM*... So pretty much everything that matters?

Comment: @ChanganAuto corrected the wording, if that's the problem.

Comment: Either way you need good backups that include a list of installed apps to make it easy to reinstall everything. You did not say from what model to what model. Often issues are more related to proprietary video & WiFi drivers. Is system UEFI with gpt? If not now would be a good time to change. Is boot drive SSD, if not that would probably make bigger improvement than CPU change.

Comment: @oldfred I'm not using proprietary video nor wifi drivers. My system is UEFI and I'm switching from a 4th generation i5 to possibly ryzen 9 5900x or 7900x, still haven't made up my mind yet. My biggest concern is if it's possible to skip reinstalling, and even more so reconfiguring, software..

Comment: I did have an issue re-using power supply. OId one supposedly was the newer configuration, but new Intel system would not boot. New power supply solved problem.  And then case did not have compatible USB3 ports on front. Older new build only had USB-c port on motherboard. So I now only do a total new build to have everything latest. I was able to boot external SSD configured with 12th gen Intel with UEFI install on Intel based 2006 BIOS laptop. Grub BIOS boot stanza only thing on old HDD in laptop but both systems were Intel.

Comment: A few months ago I went from Intel to AMD. After swapping things over, there were zero problems. Did make sure though to install the microcode, gpu drivers and reran sensors_detect.